# Want OS on HDD outside of Hardware Raid

Tags: raid, hp

I Work for a tech company. They got rid of some outdated hardware and I ended up with a couple old HP Z800s.

one of those has an HP PN XP310AA which is an HP LSI 9212 4-Port SAS 6 Gb/s Internal RAID Card.

I have four easy spots for HDDs. Those are all connected through the Raid Card. I think I can partition one of those to have the operating system on but I'd rather have all four "swappable" in the RAID.

So what I'm looking for is a way to connect a fifth drive into the motherboard and have it look there for the boot info/OS. I think they may have flashed the motherboard? not sure. I plugged in a hard drive to the first port on the motherboard but even the bios doesn't see it. not sure where to go. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are at least barking at the wrong place. Voting to migrate the question to [su].

Comment: What is your fifth disk, because the motherboard support up to SATA2?